# Ban coroutine not executing [no errors] | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm creating a new bot (my third time now, but it's been a while) and I am creating a simple ban command. It is line-for-line the same as my other commands, with the addition of the `@commands.has_permissions()` decorator and an embed to display the ban. However, after adding some prints to show where it gets to, it doesn't make it past `await user.ban()`.

```py
# ---BAN---
@client.command(name="ban", pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.User=None, *, reason: str=None):
    if not user:
        await ctx.send("Specify a user")
        return
    embed = discord.Embed (
        color = discord.Color.magenta()
    )
    embed.add_field(name=f"{user} was banned!", value=f"For reason: {reason}", inline=False)
    await user.ban()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please specify a **valid** user!")
```

No error is thrown, but it only gets to `await user.ban()` before just stopping. Is my user wrong somehow, or did I make an obvious mistake?

Comment: You should add an `else: raise error` to your error handler so that you can see the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'User' object has no attribute 'ban' , instead you need to pass a member object:

```
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member=None, *, reason: str=None):
```

And you're not getting any errors because `@ban.error` is catching them but is only handling the `BadArgument` exception while the rest are ignored.